# Create Reversing Linked List

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, error-handling, linked-list, reverse

**Java Code:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pBfp.png
[image]
I'm trying to reverse Linked List, but I keep getting
StackOverFlow Error and I can't figure out why ...

I would be happy if anyone could help me here

```
public static void reverseLinkedList(IntNode head) {
    IntNode current = head;
    IntNode next = current.getNext();

    while (next != null) {
        IntNode temp = current;
        current = next;
        next = next.getNext();
        current.setNext(temp);
    }
    System.out.println(current);
}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:538)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:125)
    at IntNode.toString(IntNode.java:31)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:168)
    at IntNode.toString(IntNode.java:31)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
```

Comment: Please copy the code into the question, not an image of the code...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem did

Comment: What's the trace of the error? A SO is almost always caused by recursion, and there's no obvious recursion here, so one of the methods you're using must be recursive and is never ending.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Now I wrote the error. I have checked in depth and have no recursive call

Comment: @S.O.M It looks like your `toString` method of the class is calling itself (probably indirectly). Make sure you aren't trying to turn the whole class into a string into that method. You can't pass the instance to a StringBuilder inside `toString`, since that will cause `toString` to be run again.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Ok thx, i will check it

Answer (score 2):

The *stackoverflow* error itself is not in the `reverseLinked` list. It is the `ToString` that will raise that error. But it is caused because your reverse linked list creates an infinite loop: two nodes that point to each other.

You should each time have a reference to three consecutive nodes. So:

```
… ← B   C → D → E → …
    ↑   ↑   ↑
```

We can each time let C point to B as next node:

```
… ← B ← C   D → E → …
    ↑   ↑   ↑
```

and then move to the next item:

```
… ← B ← C   D → E → …
        ↑   ↑   ↑
```

If the third pointer is `null`, we only need to let the second pointer take the first one as next, and set the next of the second to `null`:

```
… ← Y   Z → null
    ↑   ↑   ↑
```

So we convert this to:

```
… ← Y ← Z   null
    ↑   ↑   ↑
```

So we can implement this in an algorithm as follows:

```
public static IntNode reverseLinkedList(IntNode node0) {
    if(node0 == null) {
        return null;
    }
    IntNode node1 = node0.getNext();
    node0.setNext(null);
    if(node1 == null) {
        return node0;
    }
    Int node2 = node1.getNext();
    node1.setNext(node0);
    while(node2 != null) {
        node1.setNext(node0);
        node0 = node1;
        node1 = node2;
        node2 = node2.getNext();
    }
    node1.setNext(node0);
    return node1;
}
```

We return as result the new head of the linked list.